# Is it by design that opening with -S doesn't account for changes in file permission?

Tags: sessions

If `a_session` is created via `:mksession`, when reopening that session via `vim -S a_session`, Vim doesn't take into account that file permissions of some of the opened files might have changed in the meanwhile.

Here are the repro steps.

1. Open `a_file` which is not readonly, and make sure that's the case by verifying `:echo &readonly` gives `0`;
2. save the session, `:mksession`;
3. close Vim, `:q`;
4. in the terminal, make the file readonly `chmod -w a_file`;
5. reopen Vim via `vim -S Session.vim`;
6. verify that `:echo &readonly` still returns `0`, **which I find strange**
7. run `:e`
8. verify that `:echo &readonly` returns `1` now.

Is what happens at step 6 by design?

Answer (score 3):

Session is simply a VimScript file. You can read through it and see what is going on.

What it does, it re-creates buffer(s) and after that it attempts to restore all previously saved options. By doing so it may overwrite any automatic settings such as `&readonly` that were set while the new buffer was being loaded.

IMO, saving options into session script should be avoided.

Refer to [`:h 'sessionoptions'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27sessionoptions%27) to do adjustments.

Comment: Reference to [:h 'sessionoptions'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27sessionoptions%27)

Comment: tpope's obsession does some nice things regarding sessions, IMO, including adjusting `sessionoptions`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I don't use it. What good could it do except setting it once?

Comment: https://github.com/tpope/vim-obsession